# Embedding local images with relative paths using HoverTool in Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am trying to create a plot where when you hover over a glyph it shows an image like [this snake example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/tools.html#userguide-tools-inspectors) from the docs:

If I provide a pandas dataframe series/DataSourceColumn `@images` containing absolute paths, the code works fine when running using `show`, but if I provide using relative paths to the current working directory (subfolder_from_cwd/filename.png) the images do not display when using `show`. My goal is to make a portable html file containing the data, but it seems with absolute paths the `save` `output_save` to html functions do not embed the images, so I need to use relative paths.

I have tried:

- Including the current working directory name in the folder path
- Changing `file://@images` to `@images`

But I am not sure what else to try.

Thanks for any help.

```py
def make_bokeh_plot(dataframe, title):
    def style(p):
        p.title.align = 'center'
        p.title.text_font_size = '18pt'
        p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '12pt'
        p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '12pt'
        p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '12pt'
        p.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '12pt'

        return p



    #make a histogram, keeping the image path
    arr_df, frequencies, edges  = make_histogram_df(dataframe.score.values, bins=100)

    #Make a list of the paths indexes by histrogram index bins
    img_path_series=make_img_path_series(edges,dataframe)
    #merge it with arr_df
    arr_df["images"]=img_path_series
    print(arr_df["images"].head())

    #Make df into a bokeh friendly format 
    arr_src = ColumnDataSource(arr_df)

    # Set up the figure same as before
    p = figure(plot_width = 500, plot_height = 500, title = title,
                x_range=(0, 1),
              x_axis_label = 'Scores', y_axis_label = 'Count')

    # Add a quad glyph with source this time
    p.quad(bottom=0, top='count', left='left', right='right', source=arr_src,
           fill_color='red', line_color='black')

    # Add style to the plot
    styled_p = style(p)

    # Add a hover tool referring to the formatted columns
    hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [('Delay', '@f_interval'),
                                  ('Count', '@f_count'),
                                  ('Image', '@images')])

    # src="file://@images" height="200" alt="@imgs" width="200"
    #file://
    hover = HoverTool(tooltips ="""
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img
                        src="file://@images" alt="@imgs" 
                        style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                        border="2"
                    ></img>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span style="font-size: 15px;">@f_count @f_interval</span>
                    <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #696;">($x, $y)</span>
                </div>
            """)


    # Add the hover tool to the graph
    styled_p.add_tools(hover)

    show(p)

    return p
```

When running a server via `bokeh serve --show script.py` the images do not display even with absolute paths. Similarly, I tried various ways of writing the relative path when running it as a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't work. Browsers will not load `file://` URLs from pages that were loaded via HTTP. To make this work, the image files will have to be served from a real web server and loaded via `http://` URLs.

Comment: I see thank you, so that is why it works only when running using `show` and not as a webserver. So do you know what is the Bokeh idiomatic way of hosting local images for interactive plotting? 

If it is to create an web server externally to Bokeh, that is OK, albeit a bit surprising to me.

Comment: If you make a "directory format" app with a `static` subdirectory, Bokeh will automatically serve it under `<appname>/static`. Otherwise, Bokeh is a Tornado application, you can start it "by hand" (programmatically) and add any additional custom Tornado request handlers you'd like.

Comment: Amazing that works nicely! I spent a long time trying to figure out what the issue was (as I had already tried using it as an app, with subfolders) but I did not realise that the folder had to be called "static", thank you!

Comment: @bigreddot Could you expand on that comment in your answer to make an explicit minimal working example? I believe that is the answer a user who arrives here would want to see :)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue. What works for me is to use relative paths (the image files are in the same directory as the generated HTML, so I just provide the filenames) and replace `src="file://@images"` with `src="@images"`.